# I am trying to install libgtk2.0-dev on ubuntu 14 but getting some error

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu-14.04

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.27.3) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (>= 2.21.0) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libatk1.0-dev (>= 1.29.2) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.6.4-6.1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxext-dev (>= 1:1.0.1-2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxinerama-dev (>= 1:1.0.1-4.1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxi-dev (>= 1:1.0.1-4) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxrandr-dev (>= 1:1.2.99)
                 Depends: libxcursor-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxfixes-dev (>= 1:3.0.0-3) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxcomposite-dev (>= 1:0.2.0-3) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxdamage-dev (>= 1:1.0.1-3) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about) (but read their rules before posting).

Answer (score 1):

seems you got broken Packages, try this command:

***sudo apt-get -f install***

if it don't work either, try installing synaptic package manager on ubuntu Software center, run it, search for any broken dependencies and uninstall them...then, search from there GTK libraries, and install them.

if it's still not working, try the command aptitude. if it's not installed, install it by running on terminal:

***sudo apt-get install aptitude***

then, run: ***sudo aptitude install libgtk2.0-dev***